# ember cli environment configuration

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Could someone please provide an example for this. I am not getting this to work.

http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#Environments

I have set an environment variable in my config/environment.js file. In a route action I want to access this variable. But ENV is undefined.

**environment.js**

```
if (environment === 'test') {
   ENV.APP.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL = 'http://www.purplerow.com';
}
if (environment === 'production') {
   ENV.APP.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
}
```

**Route**

```
import ENV from 'my-demo-app/config/environment';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
     doSomething: function() {
       console.log(ENV.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL); // ENV is undefined
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that `ENV` is returned in your `./config/environment.js`.

In general it should look like follows:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'app',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance when it is created
      // Also put default values here

      REPORTING_SERVICE_URL = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
    }
  };

  // overwrite default values for different environments as needed

  if (environment === 'development') {

  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    ENV.APP.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL = 'http://www.purplerow.com';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Then you can use it in your application code:

```
import ENV from './config/environment';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
     doSomething: function() {
       console.log(ENV.APP.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL);
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing - I am using the same code. Except, "import ENV from '../config/environment';" (with just one instead of two dots it throws an error: Could not find module ...)

Comment: This is weird, the exact code works for me, I just verified.

Comment: What is your ember version? I am using 1.13.7

Comment: The same as yours, 1.13.7 with Ember CLI 1.13.8

Comment: And, this import path is correct? "import ENV from './config/environment';"

Comment: Yes, this is how it is in my code (with single dot). But you can use your application prefix as well.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. Now it is working - I just quit the debug-mode in Chrome. In debug-mode it is not working... don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your variable this way:

```
ENV.APP.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL = 'http://www.purplerow.com';
```

But accessing it this way:

```
ENV.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL
```

You should either remove `APP` when setting or add it while getting, e.g.:

```
ENV.APP.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL
```

If it is `undefined`, make sure that you did not introduced any syntax that may break the environment. Basically, `config/environment.js` should look something like this:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: "my-demo-app",
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: "/",
    locationType: "auto"
  };
  return ENV;
};
```

Take notice that the name of the variable that you export (in this case it's `ENV`) does not have to match the variable name that you import. It should just import everthing that is exported in the file and put it into the variable you named in `import`. If it is `undefined`, you basically export `undefined`.

Comment: You are right, but this is a typo. ENV is undefined.

Comment: I updated the answer. If you can paste here an example `environment.js` file that is not working it may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am not getting the point... I did not name the variable undefined. It is clear that the variable name does not matter. I could name it 'myconfigvar' and use 'myconfigvar.APP.REPORTING_SERVICE_URL' but myconfigvar is still undefined

Comment: True, I just mean that something must be wrong with the file that is exporting - `environment.js`. Until you paste it there is nothing we can help.

Comment: The environment.js looks exactly like the one posted by smirnov. I also have my code in the question. If there were an error in my environment.js, the app would not build - I just tested this.